# Mongodb Manual Padding, doc per day

Tags: mongodb

I've a server running 24h inserting 1 document into a collection every minute (so, 1440 docs a day) per device, but it can be more or less (like 1000 or 3000 docs/day).

I would need to put them all together in one doc per device, because after a couple of months, having 10 devices would be 10devices * 1440/day * 60days = 432k docs (too much to work with).

So, the idea is to put them all together per day, so each device will have one doc per day.

My first idea was to create a document per day and add the docs inside this doc (embedding), but then, the main doc grows too much and mongodb needs to reallocate it so the database grows to much because of reallocation.

My second idea was to use manual padding, create one doc with "1440" empty docs embedded inside, and every minute replace one empty doc for a real one.. But how can I do this? $unset and $set? The thing is it will never be 1440 docs exactly per day so I'm not sure how to use manual padding in my situation.

Hope you can help me!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Since there aren't many devices, perhaps a different collection for each device, a daily document (the date), with an array or hash of entries. This will then give you only 10xdays documents.

Comment: If you need to cross reference between devices and days, then use one collection with 10 documents per day, indexed by date & device, filled with an array or hash of entries.

Comment: @user975033 I said 10 but it could be thousands! How can I prefill the  doc per day if I don't know how many embedded docs it will have?

Comment: Not sure about pre-fill, but to make the DB smaller, have you tried just making one doc per day filled with an array of entries, each entry added to the bottom of the array as they come in. [device, id, data..]. Each entry just adds to the array. this should only add the bytes involved, no extra indexing would add no extra DB space is my guess.

Comment: @user975033 I've tried it but it creates reallocation so the doc has to be moved several times and the db size grows too fast!

Answer (score 0):

First, a preliminary question - why do you say that 432k docs is too much to work with? With appropriately designed indexes and queries, there should be no trouble at all from a MongoDB perspective with that number. If you can say a little bit more about why that number of documents presents a problem we might be in a better position to help with a solution, whether it is a different schema design or something else.

There is a [discussion in the the MongoDB docs about manual padding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#can-i-manually-pad-documents-to-prevent-moves-during-updates). As it mentions there, mongod will adjust the padding factor for a collection automatically if there are a lot of document moves, although the padding factor is limited to 4 so probably does not help your case.

What is more likely to help in your case is the usePowerOf2Sizes flag, which causes mongod to allocate documents in sizes that are powers of 2. This does accomplishes two things:

- It leaves some extra room after each move for additional in-place expansion before the next move, thus reducing the number of moves, and
- It can make more effective use of the disk space.

The following little experiment illustrates the last point:

```
function one(usep2) {

    // set up the collection
    db.dropDatabase()
    db.createCollection('c')
    if (usep2)
        printjson(db.runCommand({collMod: "c", usePowerOf2Sizes: true}))

    // create some docs
    for (var id=0; id<500; id++)
        db.c.insert({_id:id, x:[]})

    // grow them
    for (var i=0; i<500; i++) {
        for (var id=0; id<200; id++) {
            db.c.update({_id:id}, {$push:{x:i}})
        }
    }

    // print stats
    var s = db.c.stats(1024)
    var avg = s.avgObjSize
    var stg = s.storageSize
    print('average size: ' + avg + ' kB, storage: ' + stg + ' kB')
}
```

Running this function twice illustrates the effect of the usePowerOf2Sizes flag:

```
> one(false)
average size: 2.632 kB, storage: 21980 kB

> one(true)
{ "usePowerOf2Sizes_old" : false, "usePowerOf2Sizes_new" : true, "ok" : 1 }
average size: 3.22 kB, storage: 10920 kB
```

With the flag, average storage per document is greater, but overall storage size is less because of more effective management of the free list.

Finally, if you do choose to try manual padding, you can do it by including a padding field when you first create the document and then immediately unsetting it with $unset, as illustrated at the [discussion on manual padding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#can-i-manually-pad-documents-to-prevent-moves-during-updates) linked previously. But I do encourage you to investigate all these possibilities and take measurements using db.c.stats().

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Bruce! I said 432k but it could be millions, the thing is if I need to report a couple of days it will be about 1440*2 records to find inside the big collection (maybe millions of docs). I think, the best solution is to "group" them by day, but pushing 1500 docs inside another one is to expensive (reallocation extra space). I've already tried the Power of 2 sizes but it's not enough for this. I'm going to check for mongodb manual padding link you've posted!

Comment: OK. Note that finding a few thousand records inside a collection of millions of documents will be fast if you index the field or fields you are searching on using ensureIndex(). The indexes of course will take some space. You can use hierarchical document structures kind of like an index to make access fast, but you can only do that for one kind of search, whereas you can have multiple indexes to support different kinds of efficient search.

Answer (score 0):

Probably to late to help, but..

Insert them as individual documents into Collection1.   Then once a day take all the documents from the previous day, group them by device and combine them into one document per device and save them in Collection2.

This way you don't need to know how big each aggregated document will be ahead of time and you can make best use of the file space since you know exactly how much space it will take when aggregating them into the second collection.

Collection1 can be a TTL collection and automatically delete the old data.  Or you could simply use a collection per day and drop yesterday's collection after it has been combined into the aggregate.   This may be the fastest solution since the drop of the collection is very fast.